com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission added in manifest file but showing error
Error is
Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.
If you don't include this permission in your manifest file, your advertising identifier will be zeroed out. This may break your advertising and analytics use cases, and cause loss of revenue. Learn more
You can remove these errors by updating your advertising ID declaration
info_outline
Apps that target Android 13 (API 33) without the AD_ID permission will have their advertising identifier zeroed out. This may impact advertising and analytics use cases. Learn more
& also added
enter image description here
enter image description here
these permissions
android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_AD_ID, android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_ATTRIBUTION, android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_TOPICS, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID, com.vidb.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION
But still showing error ....
Fix this issue enter image description here
added  inside minifest file

This might be useful for you. Check out this answer. If the prblm still arise add your manfiest.xml file together with the pubspec.yaml file code in question for further assistance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
